# Certificate Issues while connecting to Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-s3

My C# code is trying to pull some files from an Amazon S3 bucket. This code works fine on my development as well as on UAT server. However, when I run this on my production server, I get a certificate error.

One difference between the UAT and Production servers is that on UAT there is no restriction on outbound internet access. On Production servers free outbound internet access is not allowed. we open only selective URLs as per requirements.

We have already opened access to s3.amazonaws.com. We have also ensured that this access works fine using WinSCP tool. However, when my code tries to do the same, I get the following error:

> WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Server Certificate Verification Failed: Issuer is not trusted.

The source code is attached below:

```
s3HostName = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3HostName"]);
s3UserName = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3UserName"]);
s3Password = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3Password"]);

LocalFilePath = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFilePath"]);
s3Folder = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3Folder"]);
LocalFileFolder = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFileFolder"]);

LocalFolder = LocalFilePath + yesterday + "\\";
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.S3,
    HostName = s3HostName,
    UserName = s3UserName,
    Password = s3Password,
};
TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
transferOptions.TransferMode = WinSCP.TransferMode.Automatic;
transferOptions.FilePermissions = null;
transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = false;

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    log.Debug("Open session for s3");
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    if (!Directory.Exists(LocalFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalFolder);
    }

    //to download files
    session.GetFiles(s3Folder + "*" + yesterday + ".csv", LocalFolder);
    session.Close();
    log.Debug("Closed session for s3");
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy that intercepts TLS requests and routes them through it? Such systems often present different TLS certificates that are self-signed by the proxy, and require additional root trust certificates to be installed. Otherwise they are (rightly) rejected for tampering with TLS connections as they are effectively a Man-in-the-Middle. If this is the case, then you either need to get S3 HTTPS requests to be completely excluded from the proxy, or have your production servers install the appropriate additional root certificates so that the certificate from the proxy appears to be valid

Comment: Well, there is a firewall in between through which all requests pass. However, when I use the WinSCP tool directly, it works fine. Only when I try it through code, it crashes with the above error.

Comment: Maybe WinSCP has its own certificate store (like Firefox does, compared to Chrome which uses the Windows one) and some custom certification stuff for the proxy installed on your production machines aren't being picked up by it?

Comment: Post session log files both from your code (`Session.SessionLogPath`) and the WinSCP GUI successfully connecting from the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue using the oldest trick in the book. Reinstalled WinSCP. Its all working fine now.